# TPC mappint generate the base class table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to achieve TPC mapping by code-first, and I have read this article:
[Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 3 – Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

I've wrote the code as below.

```
namespace TPCTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (TestContext context = new TestContext())
            {
                Manager m = new Manager();
                m.AnnualSalary = 100000;
                m.Name = "Allen";
                m.Sex = true;
                m.Id = 1;

                Worker w = new Worker();
                w.Id = 2;
                w.Name = "John";
                w.Sex = true;
                w.MonthlyPay = 5000;

                context.empSet.Add(m);
                context.empSet.Add(w);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Sex { get; set; }
    }

    class Manager : Employee
    {
        public decimal AnnualSalary { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }

    class Worker : Employee
    {
        public decimal MonthlyPay { get; set; }
    }

    class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> empSet { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>().Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapInheritedProperties();
                    m.ToTable("Manager");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>().Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapInheritedProperties();
                    m.ToTable("Worker");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        }
    }
}
```

But after running the code, I found the Employee table also exist in database, anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently, [this issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/30086074-6773-4b83-bed5-88a401fb2a4e) still exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Use EF 5.0 or higher!**

The issue seems to be fixed since that version. With EF 4.3.1 I could reproduce the behavior. So just update.